# Xcode [noob] Release of objects, because of memory and CPU load

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova

As a c# unity and php programmer i'm a complete noob in objective-c. I managed to copy paste a project together with cordoba-phonegap-objective C to make a project wich at its base concept is a mirror like app ( with al kinds of extra's, still to be programmed) .. the mirror works, but in xcode the load of the cpu and memory keeps adding and finally crashes.. as i'm searching i think i made a mistake not releasing objects but it's a lucky guess.. i hope you can help me...

```
#import "CanvasCamera.h"
@implementation CanvasCamera
- (void)startCapture:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command
{
self.session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
self.session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPreset352x288;
self.device = [self frontCamera];
self.input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:self.device error:nil];

self.output = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
self.output.videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA] forKey:(id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey];

dispatch_queue_t queue;
queue = dispatch_queue_create("canvas_camera_queue", NULL);
[self.output setSampleBufferDelegate:(id)self queue:queue];
[self.session addInput:self.input];
[self.session addOutput:self.output];
[self.session startRunning];
}

- (AVCaptureDevice *)frontCamera {
 NSArray *devices = [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
for (AVCaptureDevice *device in devices) {
    if ([device position] == AVCaptureDevicePositionFront) {
        return device;
    }
}
return nil;

}

- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{
CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);
uint8_t *baseAddress = (uint8_t *)CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer);
size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer);
size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer);
size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer);

CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGContextRef newContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(baseAddress, width, height, 8, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);

CGImageRef newImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(newContext);
CGContextRelease(newContext);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
UIImage *image= [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newImage scale:1.0 orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
NSString *encodedString = [imageData base64Encoding];

NSString *javascript = @"CanvasCamera.capture('data:image/jpeg;base64,";
javascript = [javascript stringByAppendingString:encodedString];
javascript = [javascript stringByAppendingString:@"');"];
[self.webView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:) withObject:javascript waitUntilDone:YES];

CGImageRelease(newImage);
CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Review your use of NSAutoreleasepool, looking into Objective C's Automatic Reference Counting, and [this documentation from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAutoreleasePool_Class/index.html).

Comment: I don't understand the concept of the whole NSAutoreleasepool... i tried several things ..but it's still abracadabra for me... could you help me by explaining it in my code?